# Как снова начать считывать файл с первой строки при достижении последней строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Имеется код, нужно начать считывание файла с начала при достижении последней строки.

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r') #в файле 20 строк
for i in range(40):
    line = file.readline()
file.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте метод [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.seek) чтобы переместить указатель.

Код ниже 40 раз выведет первую строку файла:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in range(40):
        line = f.readline()
    
        # Возвращаемся к началу файла
        f.seek(0)
```

---

А код ниже выведет все строки из файла, переместит указатель в начало файла и еще раз выведет строки:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(repr(line))

    # Возвращаемся к началу файла
    f.seek(0)

    print("Еще раз!")

    for line in f:
        print(repr(line))
```

---

Можно еще поиграться с итераторами.

Суть в том, что мы создадим итератор и будем дергать из него строки файла и если достигнем конца, то тот выбросит исключение `StopIteration`, а мы это поймаем и вернемся в начало файла:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    it = iter(f)

    for i in range(40):
        try:
            line = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            f.seek(0)

            line = next(it)

        print(i, repr(line))
```

---

Но это, по сути, велосипед. Т.к. в ответе рядом через cycle и islice происходит тоже самое :)

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

with open('file.txt') as fh:
    for line in islice(cycle(fh), 40):
        ...
```

Comment: cycle хранит все значения в памяти, не круто

Comment: @andreymal, в вопросе указано, что в файле 20 строк. В такой ситуации лучше всего вообще вычитать файл целиком, завершить работу с файлом, и дальше уже работать с вычитанным содержимым.

Comment: Хмм, интересно, а если в одной строке до символа переноса каретки - несколько гигабайт? :)

Comment: @nobody то не стоит открывать файл как текстовый и использовать `readline`, как это делает автор вопроса. Да и вообще это в корне изменит смысл вопроса.